# Issue when run app with Grails

Tags: java, eclipse, grails, cmd

I'm a newbie in Grails Framework, I've downloaded Grails version 2.4.4 and set Path to it.
I create new application (like "hello world") but when run it with command (after cd application folder): grails run-app , 
cmd was stopped at this line : Configuring classpath.
Then I google, and try to use this way : setting "verbose" in BuildConfig.groovy file and it still like before with these errors :

```
| Error Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.5
org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.5
        at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:370)
        at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:217)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.resolveCachedArtifactDescriptor(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:525)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.getArtifactDescriptorResult(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:509)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:409)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:363)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.process(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:351)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.doRecurse(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:494)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:458)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:363)
```

What can I do next?? and why it has these error, and what can I do for running this application.
P/s : Java version that I use is Java 1.6.0, OS: window 7.

Thank for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a proxy issue, you can execute below commands:

```
grails add-proxy "client" "--host=yourHostName" "--port=8080" "--username=***" "--password='PASSWORD_GOES_HERE'"
grails set-proxy client
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the notation is incorrect for your dependency. You have:

`org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.5`

this includes a `jar` reference, which is unnecessary. Can you try:

`org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.5`

Also, it looks like version `1.7.9` is available as of December 2014, if you want to use the latest.